# AngularJs unit test, resolve url params with colon(:)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have  Rest url like mydomain.com/restapi/somemethod/paramValue .

In my angular js app the same url look like mydomain.com/restapi/somemethod/**:paramValue**
and when i invoke the function everything works fine.

But now i am writing some unit test and wanted to use the same url(I created some var and sharing them throughout the app using factory) like :

```
$httpBackend.expectGET(SomeService.getDataUrl).respond(mockResponse);
```

The problem is I am getting error like

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET restapi/somemethod/1
Expected GET restapi/somemethod/:paramValue
```

Which make sense. Is there some way to invoke the angularJs url resolving mechanism so that in unit test the value of the params can be replaced with there values?

**NOTE** : The whole point of sharing urls using service is that i wanted to make sure that urls used in production and test code are the same.

Comment: `i wanted to make sure that urls used in production and test code are the same.` that is not necessary because if they aren't the same, the tests would fail anyway. I think its better to 'manually' input the url in the test like `$httpBackend.expectGET('restapi/somemethod/1');`

Comment: @Tim Castelijns That's true but however reusing the same urls i am sure that test will at-least not fail due to typo in urls. Plus i am sticking more to DRY principle.

Comment: DRY is a good practice! However in unittests that doesn't really matter because test code is most likely going to be removed from the project before release anyway.

Comment: @Tim Castelijns No that's not the case we have CI which runs all the test before every commit and in production we need to ship the test , client requirements.

Comment: Ok I understand. However test code does not impact production code so in the end it is not as important whether or not your tests are designed perfectly. Sorry I couldn't give a proper answer

Comment: @Tim Castelijns Tx for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way to invoke the angularJs url resolving mechanism so that in unit test the value of the params can be replaced with there values?

Use the interceptor to replace the params:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
   'request': function(config) {
   // intercept request
  },

'response': function(response) {
   // intercept response
   }
 };
});
```

The Angular team uses something like this in the project test suite:

```
  it('should allow manipulation of request', function() {
    module(function($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
        return {
          request: function(config) {
            config.url = '/intercepted';
            config.headers.foo = 'intercepted';
            return config;
          }
        };
      });
    });
    inject(function($http, $httpBackend, $rootScope) {
      $httpBackend.expect('GET', '/intercepted', null, function(headers) {
        return headers.foo === 'intercepted';
      }).respond('');
      $http.get('/url');
      $rootScope.$apply();
    });
  });
```

**References**

- [AngularJS: httpSpec.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/httpSpec.js)